# andengine remove AnimatedSprite in LoopEntityModifier

Tags: android, andengine

I have an AnimatedSprite element, I want to apply some modifiers to this (AlphaModifier, ScaleModifier, ...)

After the modifier finished, the AnimatedSprite element should removed.
removeFace() method working properly when calling normally. However I am calling it in onModifierFinished() method, then I am getting errors. I was implemented like this.

```
void removeBallWithModifier(final AnimatedSprite ball) {

    final LoopEntityModifier em = new LoopEntityModifier(
            new SequenceEntityModifier(new ParallelEntityModifier(
                    new AlphaModifier(1, 1, 0.4f), new ScaleModifier(1, 1,
                            0.4f), new RotationByModifier(1, 270))), 1,
            new IEntityModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                        IEntity pItem) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onModifierFinished(
                        IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                    ball.setVisible(false);
                    removeFace(ball);
                }
            });
    ball.registerEntityModifier(em);
}

void removeFace(final AnimatedSprite face) {
    final PhysicsConnector facePhysicsConnector = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(face);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(facePhysicsConnector);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(facePhysicsConnector.getBody());

    this.mScene.unregisterTouchArea(face);
    this.mScene.detachChild(face);

    System.gc();
}
```

stack trace:

```
02-20 00:56:39.008: W/dalvikvm(14094): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1402)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:284)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:591)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:586)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
02-20 00:56:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(14094):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this

```
  YourClassName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      ball.setVisible(false);
                       removeFace(ball);
                            }
                         });
```